# Why won't windows boot in virt-manager KVM VM?

Tags: linux-kvm, virt-manager

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.makeuseof.com/run-windows-apps-on-linux-with-winapps/) on how to run windows apps seamlessly in using winapps and my VM won't boot. It gives the message "Boot failed: Could not read from CDROM (code 0004)". I made sure that "SATA CDROM 1" was enabled in boot options, but no change. I also tried creating a new VM with UEFI hardware, but it would either give me a different error code that I can't reproduce rn or boot to the UEFI shell.

Comment: have you "mounted" an iso into the cdrom?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on the same thing trying to follow. I fixed this by installing an actual windows ISO on CDROM 1. I got it directly from Microsoft the ISO you download just has files on it. It's not clear in the instructions. Just make sure you add CDROM 2 with that ISO file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).